# Equivalent of publish subject in RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I notice that publish subject is not implemented in RxJS. Is there a way to simulate something like it ?
I want to receive only the data that is sent after I subscribe, without the last value. Exactly the behavior of an event emitter in angular 2.
All the other subject types seem to store the last value and send it.

With regards

Answer (score 11):

Ok, so what I was searching for is the simple Subject.

Answer (score 3):

This information can help you:

> https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md